# Efficient way to scrape Reddit using praw?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am working on a project that involves scraping comments, and subsequently applying sentiment analysis, for a very large (10k+) set of terms. The per-term comment number to scrape is not that large actually, I would only want to retrieve comments from the last 1 week (or maybe 1 month at most). However, I found the speed rather disappointing. For instance even this very simple snippet below runs for over 3 minutes. Assuming such a speed and 14,000 terms in total, my code would need to run continuously for over a month in order to complete the task!

```
term = "fastly stock fsly"
results = reddit.subreddit("all").search(term, sort="comments", limit=None)

for submission in results:
    for top_level_comment in submission.comments:
        if not isinstance(top_level_comment, praw.models.MoreComments):
            if all(word for word in term.lower().split() if word in top_level_comment.body.lower()):
                print(top_level_comment.body)
```

Is there any chance to significantly cut back processing time? I see that the double for loop is a terrible construct but not quite sure if it's possible to avoid here. Furthermore, I am aware that the inner for loop loops through a potentially very long list even though I will, most probably, only need the top 10-20 comments but it's not clear to me if it is possible to apply the `subreddit.search()` for a specific time period. I don't see any parameter for that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to decrease some time is to change the `term.lower().split()` to a list that you can reference instead of trying to split the string every time in the for loop (creating additional wasted processing time).

Using a try-catch block is preferable to isinstance if you are looking to increase speed as the try-catch is pythonic and heavily optimized compared to isinstance.

With that tweak, you still have 3 nested for loops giving N^3 time complexity.

```
term = "fastly stock fsly"
terms = term.lower().split()
results = reddit.subreddit("all").search(term, sort="comments", limit=None)
    
for submission in results:
    for top_level_comment in submission.comments:
        try:
            if all(word for word in terms if word in top_level_comment.body.lower()):
                print(top_level_comment.body)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

As for your if all() statement it will always evaluate to true if there is a single word that matches, I am unsure if that is the meaning that you wanted, because if so then there are ways to break that search faster (when it finds the first word matching between your lists)